# How to update widget per second in android?

Tags: android, widget, alarmmanager

## How to update widget per second ?

I used    AlarmManager but it only works on below kitkat version.

Comment: Please update your app widget much less frequently than this. Bear in mind that the user is not normally looking at their home screen, and so all you are doing is wasting CPU time and battery for no value.

Answer (score 1):

Here, i am making user wait for 30 seconds on a screen and hiding the view and hitting service when it finishes. You can customize according to your need.

```
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(31000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                timer_text.setText("Remaining Seconds. " + millisUntilFinished / 1000 + " s");
                if (count >= 30) {

                } else {
                    count++;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                timer_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                /// VOLLEY SERVICE
            }
        }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

AlarmManager cannot have a timeout less than 20 seconds.  Any timeout less than that will be rounded up.

First off, I would question whether you actually need it updated every second.  That's an incredible amount of processing power used, and pretty much against the idea of a widget.  If it needs to be updated that frequently it should be an app.  If your updates are coming from a server and you want to display them immediately, look into push messaging instead.  Then you only need to update when you receive a message, no alarms or timers needed.

Secondly-  the way you do a timer for short periods like that is via Handler.postDelayed.  It can have a much smaller resolution.  However it may not run if the phone is asleep.

Comment: I tried to give it 10 seconds, but the tooltip said the minimum timeout was 60 seconds